# Returning a response from the most recent event, rather than the last async response

Tags: rxjs

I have 3 buttons on a page, each that make separate async requests. The content of this page should show the text returned from the request generated by the last button click.

If I merge these streams, the content of the page is always the text of the last completed async request, not the last click.

Here's an example. (S*) are the streams, (C) their clicks, and (R) their responses. My code will result in the S3 click being rendered on the page. However, I would like the content of S2 to be rendered, as it's the final click.

```
S1 --c-r-------------
S2 --------c---r-----
S3 ------c----------r
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [switchAll](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchAll).  Something like:

```
const s1 = clickStream1.map(() => someAsync1())
const s2 = clickStream2.map(() => someAsync2())
const s3 = clickStream3.map(() => someAsync3())

const stream = merge(s1, s3, s3).pipe(
    switchAll()
)
```

Each time a new click occurs (and a new async action starts), the stream will "forget" any previous in-flight action and start listening to the new action.